# How to change setting for debug version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In project structure I have release and debug build types [image]

How can I set different versions of `NetworkSettings.java` file for different build types.
For example for release

```
public class NetworkSettings {
    private final static String SERVER_URL="releaseserver.com";
    private final static int SERVER_PORT=80;

    public static String getServerUrl()
    {
        return SERVER_URL;
    }
    public static int getServerPort()
    {
        return SERVER_PORT;
    }
}
```

and for debug

```
public class NetworkSettings {
    private final static String SERVER_URL="testserver.com";
    private final static int SERVER_PORT=80;

    public static String getServerUrl()
    {
        return SERVER_URL;
    }
    public static int getServerPort()
    {
        return SERVER_PORT;
    }
}
```

I want to do it using build types so as not to forget change it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain it in many ways.

For example you can use your  BuildConfig.
Also with Gradle, you have the ability to **generate additional fields in the BuildConfig class**.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_VAR", "true"
        }
        main {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_VAR", "false"
        }
        ...
    }    
}
```

And then..

```
if (BuildConfig.MY_VAR) {

}
```

Otherwise you can use **provide a different implementation of the same class in a different flavor**.

Pay attention:you have to omit this class from the `main` source

```
app/
|--libs/
|--src/
   |--flavor1/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--Flavor.java
   |--flavor2/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--Flavor.java
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--...
```

Of course you to declare these flavors in your build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}
```

You can use also **the build types**, adding the folders named debug and release.

```
   app/
    |--libs/
    |--src/
       |--debug/
       |  |--java/
       |     |--com/example/
       |        |--MyClass.java
       |--release/
       |  |--java/
       |     |--com/example/
       |        |--MyClass.java
       |--main/
          |--java/
          |  |--...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, i dn think ide will support something like this

In your class..

```
private final static boolean DEVELOPMENT_MODE = true;
private final static String SERVER_URL;
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 80;

static{
    SERVER_URL = ((DEVELOPMENT_MODE) ? "releaseserver.com" : "testserver.com");
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change DEVELOPMENT_MODE manually. It is simplest way and I want a little automatization)